# Setting up reused navigation bar item button for left button

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am using a Navigation Bar through out my application although not controller via a Navigation Controller (added to the VCs via Storyboard).

I would like to set a left bar button item to be the same on the navigation controller through out its use. This is a stack style for the menu which will slide in:

[image]
What is the correct way to implement this button following standard practice? I can strip the bg of the button to be repeatable which is not an issue, but how do I complete the following:
1. Implement an image within the button
2. Implement this button through appearance API if possible so the code is not glue code and re-used on all VCs that have this.

If I cannot do via appearance, what would be the best approach to not have to include this code over and over again in the controllers that use this?

Further to this, is there a way to show this button item in a storyboard and be linked in the storyboard/have a use other than visually.

Comment: You can create a category for a viewController and add that navBarItem to the navBar. If you are not using that button for navigation then what is the expected result of the button? Is a menu sliding in underneath the entire bar? You can use the image property of the bar item for the image.

Comment: Yes a menu is sliding in underneath. It would be the same for multiple VCs. Would I use the image property and not stretch the image just use this as a whole image? It is not for ALL view controllers but there are 7 or so that will use this, do you still recommend a category?

Comment: @MarkM - do you have any other information on what is needed? how to create the category and method?

Comment: I would create the navbar with a CAGradient and then set the leftBarItem to the button you have displayed along with its image. You can set the action on that button to animate in your menu but if you are using this for navigation you will need to hide the backBarButton on viewwillAppear or it may be fighting for placement of your leftBarButton (Navigation controllers auto add a back button after pushing a view). Start on one view then you can instantiate that class after you get the appearance correct for reuse.

Comment: Thanks, per the question this is not part of a nav controller stack so the back button would not be an issue. I found out how to complete this the best way was to create a class for a Navigation Bar and then add the button to awakeFromNib method I can then add the bar in storyboard VCs when needed and point to the correct class. I guess this is what I was looking for. Thanks @MarkM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ok, now I'm following you. In that case just create a custom navBar class and either add that to your pch then use it where necessary or create a custom UIViewController subclass called "UIViewControllerWithNavBar" then you can use that class as a replacement for the default UIViewController class.

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewControllerWithNavBar
```

This will allow you to reuse the class throughout your app with the navBar already added.

Comment: Accepted as Answer, however my approach was to subclass UINavigationBar and use awakeFromNib for the bar appearance

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post about this issue, but for the rightBarButtonItem. I'm not sure if the "back" functionality will require tweaks, but here's the blog post if interested: http://www.codebestowed.com/ios-shared-barbuttonitems/

The basic idea is to subclass UINavigationController, give it a BarButtonItem property (self.myButton in the code below) and add code similar to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem) {
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.myButton;
    }
}
```

The blog post details how you can set this up further in InterfaceBuilder, which requires a bit of a hack (too much to go into in this answer).